# Как обработать ошибку после её выброса в интерцепторе?

Tags: javascript, angular

В самом верхнем модуле

```
    { provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: GlobalErrorHandler },
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: ErrorInterceptor, multi: true },
  ]
```

обычные ошибки до GlobalErrorHandler доходят, всё кроме тех что бросаются в HTTP_INTERCEPTORS и имеют статус код 0, то есть обычные 404 из интерцептора обрабатывается в глобальном как надо.
в интерцепторе я делаю ретрай и после 3х раз бросаю дальше. Ангуляр пятый.

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался всё норм перехватывается. Проблема была в том что сентри переписывает стандартные методы сетТаймаута и тд, и поэтому даже если все исключения отловил, всё равно шлется ошибка.